# Resetting all layers one time, when click is fired

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Within a click function, I have the below code:

```
home.addEventListener('click', () => {

       myAPP.mapview.map.layers.items.forEach(item => {
            item.visible = false;
        });
       //........... }
```

However, after the button is clicked once, it seems to continuously run/execute. How could I assure it executes, i.e. 'resets' just one time, just when the button or click function occurs?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the listener to run once, you can specify that in the addEventListener options.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

This seems a weird bug.
Do you have too many layers?
Try setting each layer's visibility instead of running them in a loop.

```
  home.addEventListener('click', () => {
    myAPP.mapview.map.findLayerById('layer1').visible = false;
    ...
    ...
  });
```